# NLTK - how to get items where the frequency distribution is greater than a specific number

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I'm trying to get the frequency distribution for a list if it's over a certain number.

Example:

```
import nltk
test_list=['aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'dd']
test_fd = nltk.FreqDist(test_list)
```

Returns:

```py
FreqDist({'aa': 2, 'dd': 2, 'bb': 1, 'cc': 1})
```

Without a loop, I am looking for all the items greater than 1.

Using Python 3.8 and NLTK 3.5

Comment: You would need to use a loop, even if you do come across a solution which 'doesn't use loop' technically would internally use a loop. Use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40555781/8661686).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding frequency distribution of a list of numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553332/finding-frequency-distribution-of-a-list-of-numbers-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
test_fd = nltk.FreqDist({k: v for k, v in test_fd.items() if v > 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `filter` and you can decide to have as output a `dict` or a `list` (of tuples):

```
test_fd = dict(filter(lambda x: x[1] > 1, nltk.FreqDist(test_list).items()))
```